# iOS Build issue in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, delegates

Hello everyone I have **developed app in flutter** and Android version is uploaded now I need the **iOS version** and for that company provided me the **delegate access to the account**. Now when I try to build the **archive of the app and try to distribute it the Xcode** say's your account doesn't have apple developer program or you are not enrolled in it so how could I get access or what should I do.
I am attaching some screenshots [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUnV5.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y1Il.jpg)
Your help is really needed thanks alot

Comment: Which stage of the construction process did you perform that received the message? This message appears in `flutter build ios` or archive?

Comment: please check the images I have built the archived but now I am unable to distribute it or upload it

Comment: Sorry, but the images you added only show your account in the appstore, what I can say is that a certificate and a developer profile are able to build and distribute an application for the testflight. What I advise you to do, check the certificates and the development profile of this developer account. To ensure that you can create a distribution certificate, you would need the App Manager permission in the appstore, which would give you access to developer.com, so your xcode would be able to automatically create certificates and distribution profiles during the archive.

Comment: how would i get the App Manager permission in the appstore will it given but he account holder or I will have to made as I also have a delegate access

Comment: The owner account must give you this permission.